# What is causing text to be displayed in a random place?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, bootloader, vga

I am trying to write some code which displays some text at a given position on the screen.

When doing some research, I found [this page](https://wiki.osdev.org/Text_UI) that shows the formula `position = (y_position * characters_per_line) + x_position;`.

Here is the snipped of code that calculates and sets the position:

```
set_cursor_pos:
  push ax
  push bx

  mov al, [ypos]
  mov bl, 80
  mul bl
  add ax, [xpos]
  mov bl, 2
  mul bl
  mov di, ax

  pop bx
  pop ax

  ret
```

This works until `ypos = 3` and `xpos = 15` After this, it seems to wrap around to the beginning. Hear are some examples:

y=2, x = 30:

[image]

y=0, x = 60:

[image]

y=3, x=15:

[image]

y=4, x=0:

[image]

As you can see, my algorithm works until `y=3, x-15`. After that, it wraps around.

Is this because there is not enough memory? Do I need to enable the A20 line? Is it another problem? If so, please can you explain what and why.

Finally, here is all. of my code:

```
org 0x7c00


mov ax, 0xB800
mov es, ax
xor di, di

cli

mov ah, 0Fh
mov si, msg
call set_cursor_pos
call print

hlt

print:
  cli
  lodsb
  stosw
  cmp al, 0
  jne print
  ret


set_cursor_pos:
  push ax
  push bx

  mov al, [ypos]
  mov bl, 80
  mul bl
  add ax, [xpos]
  mov bl, 2
  mul bl
  mov di, ax

  pop bx
  pop ax

  ret

msg db 'Hello, World', 0

xpos db 0
ypos db 4

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

Comment: Instead of just looking at the output, did you try single-stepping your code with a debugger?  Seeing the value in AX after `mul` and after `add` should have given you a big clue.  I only answered so I'd have space / formatting to show how to do it without one-operand `mul`

Comment: @PeterCordes I can't seem to find a good debugger for my host OS (macOS), installed bochs with homebrew and it doesn't seem to work fully. I also asked this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52633680/how-to-debug-custom-os-with-virtualbox and no one has answered. I am going to try and install Linux on my Mac in the next few days. Unless someone answers that post. I will then use Linux with Bochs to debug.

Comment: Developing asm without a debugger is like trying to build a robot while blindfolded.  It's just a huge waste of time to not use a debugger, especially when you're just learning (asm in general, or a new architecture, or anything you're not completely comfortable with simulating *accurately* in your head.)  Many asm bugs just crash or produce meaningless output that doesn't help you figure out what happened, unlike this one where it's relatively straightforward to see that it's the memory offset into VGA memory being miscalculated and look at just that code for possible suspects.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the tip. Are there any debuggers you would recommend for macOS? Or would you say wait until I have Linux installed on my computer with Bochs?

Comment: I don't use MacOS.  I also don't do legacy-BIOS bootloader development, my interest is performance tuning for x86-64 under modern OSes.  But I've heard good things about BOCHS.  A quick google suggests that some people have it working under OS X.  Another option for 16-bit code is DOSBOX; I think it can be configured with a built-in debugger.  qemu can also act as a GDB remote.  Your other question was asking about debugging under VirtualBox, which rules out BOCHS and other emulators.  IDK if it has support for being a GDB remote target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your operand-sizes.  `xpos` is only 1 byte, but you're reading 2 bytes with `add ax, [xpos]`.  Also, `mul bl` does `ax = al * bl`, so you're throwing away the high half of the mul-by-80 result.

i.e. `set_cursor_pos` returns with

```
di = (( (80*ypos) & 0xff) + (xpos + (ypos<<8)) ) & 0xFF) * 2
```

From your previous questions, you're targeting a 386-compatible, so you could write it with

```
movzx  di, byte [ypos]
imul   di, di, 80
movzx  ax, byte [xpos]
add    di, ax

add    di, di       ; di *= 2.  equivalent to shl di, 1  but more efficient.
```

(80 = 16 * 5, so you can also avoid `imul` and use one `lea di, [edi + edi*4]` / `shl di, 4`.  Or whatever 8086-compatible trick for multiply by a number with so few set bits.)

There is zero point in using `mul` to multiply by 2, unless you were going to use `mul bx` and use the full 32-bit result in `dx:ax`.  But even then, for 2 you should just use `add di,di` / `setc al` because the carry-out can only be 1 bit.

If `xpos` and `ypos` were 16-bit, you could use them as memory operands:

```
imul   di, [ypos], 80
add    di, [xpos]
add    di, di       ; di *= 2
```

Or of course you could keep them in registers in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the tip1 I changed xpos and ypos to a data word instead of a data byte as that method is a lot better to read.

Comment: @iProgram: human readability comes 2nd to efficiency.  That's what comments are for.  The tradeoff here is code-size vs. data size.  If you ever had to copy around xy pairs, having both fit together into a 16-bit register is nice.

Comment: True point. So this second option is still better then as it's less instructions and a smaller file size? Every byte counts in bootloaders!

Comment: Yes, I think the 2nd option is smaller.  It still has the absolute address of both xpos and ypos as separate `disp16`, even though you know they're adjacent.  But loading both with `mov dx, [xpos]` / `mov al,dh` / `mov dh,80` / `mul dh` / `mov dh,0` / `add ax, dx` / `add ax,ax` is probably more code size, even though most of those are 2-byte instructions.  If you were using it more than twice, maybe putting the address in a reg for `disp0`/`disp8` would be good.  But code-golfing for machine-code size isn't necessary unless you're up against the 510 byte limit.

Comment: (And static storage can be outside the 512-byte boot sector, if you don't need it initialized to a value.)